# Delay only since a week within approval flows

Tags: microsoft-teams, power-automate, approval-tests

Wondering if anyone else is experiencing a 2 - 5 minute delay with power automate approval emails? It has been like this all week. Teams notifications still come in right away. I never had this issue before. Thank you in advance!

I never had this issue before. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sorry but this question isn't appropriate for StackOverflow, there's no long lasting answer to your question.  I'd suggest raising it with your internal tech team or Microsoft directly.

Comment: Could you please let us know if you are still facing this issue, I did try this at our end with following flow - https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDSTS.png. Card is posted in both Teams and outlook at 1:36PM only but there has been a slight delay of few seconds but not in minutes.